# How to auto fill up input field in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to fill full name input box by inserting first name and last name input box. I just bind the data from above two values in input box, but it does not show in full name input box. Thanks in advance!!
Code:

```
                <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

                First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
                Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
                Full Name:<input ng-bind="firstName+" "+lastName>

                    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.firstName = "John";
      $scope.lastName = "Doe";
      });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ng-bind` directive for HTML attributes, see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D).

`ng-bind` can be used in other HTML tags:

```
<span ng-bind="firstName + ' ' + lastName"></span>
```

With the `input` tag, you can use these directives:

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="string"
       [name="string"]
       [required="string"]
       [ng-required="string"]
       [ng-minlength="number"]
       [ng-maxlength="number"]
       [pattern="string"]
       [ng-pattern="string"]
       [ng-change="string"]
       [ng-trim="boolean"]>
```

However, you can use the curly braces notation in the HTML `value` attribute:

```
<input value="{{firstName + ' ' + lastName}}">
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br> Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br> Full Name: <input value="{{firstName + ' ' + lastName}}">
  <span ng-bind="firstName + ' ' + lastName"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

            First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
            Full Name:<span ng-bind="fullName"></span>
     </div>

     <script>
          var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
          app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.firstName = "John";
          $scope.lastName = "Doe";
          $scope.fullName =  $scope.firstName  + " " + $scope.lastName;
       });
     </script>
```